# Sum from this month to the end of the table for a specific criteria

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need help with function required in C14
sum starts by checking month date from B11 and sum the values starting from that date forward, also need to make sure that "location" and "function" match the criteria.

Please check attached image

Tried:

```
=sumifs(A2:A8&B2:B8,A16&B16,index(D2:J8,,match(C11,D1:J1,0)))
=INDEX($D$2:$J$8,MATCH(A15&B15,A2:A8&B2:B8,0),MATCH(C11,D1:J1,0))
```

gave me error and didn't work

Comment: Welcome to the community Shady. Make sure that when asking a question, your post contains an actual question and code that you have tried to solve whatever issue you are having :) More information on that can be found in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

On top of that, using links that point to external sources hurts the longevity of your question and might make it impossible for others to use your question in the future so try to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way is to use SUMPRODUCT which will sum multiple columns, based on multiple criteria. This formula should do what you need, place it in cell C14 (the result is 150):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=A14)*($B$2:$B$8=B14)*($D$1:$J$1>=$B$11)*($D$2:$J$8))
```

[Explanation of function from Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

Comment: Nice; just B11 that needs to be fixed cell

Comment: @JvdV - thanks updated the formula, if this was my sheet I would also name the ranges :)